# Error developing Cordova plugin for Ionic app, app not building using Ionic 2 build Ios command, it doesn't find framework classes

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an Ionic 2 app that uses some native functionality for recording video with special settings and allowing the user to change them in a popover window, this was developed as a framework in Swift and integrated to the Ionic application as a Cordova plugin.

This is my config.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="com.brainshark.camerarecording" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>CameraRecording</name>
    <js-module name="CameraRecording" src="www/CameraRecording.js">
    <clobbers target="CameraRecording" /></js-module>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
            <feature name="CameraRecording">
                <param name="ios-package" value="CameraRecording" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/ios/CameraRecording.swift" />
        <framework src="libs/CameraRecording.framework" custom="true" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

This is the CameraRecording.js:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.echo = function(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3, success, error) {
  exec(success, error, "CameraRecording", "echo", [arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3]);
};
```

This is the Swift code:

```
import CameraRecording
@objc(CameraRecording) class CameraRecording : CDVPlugin, VideoRecorderPluginDelegate {

    private var callbackId:String?

    @objc(echo:) func echo(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        self.callbackId = command.callbackId
        self.commandDelegate.run {
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            let fileName = command.arguments[0] as? String ?? "\(uuid).mp4"
            let defaultResolution = command.arguments[1] as? String ?? "640x480"
            let defaultFPS = command.arguments[2] as? String ?? "30"
            let maxRecordingTime = command.arguments[3] as? String ?? "0"


            if fileName.characters.count > 0 {

                let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.brainshark.CameraRecording")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: frameworkBundle)

                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideRecordingViewController") as! VideoRecordingViewController
                viewController.delegate = self
                viewController.fileName=fileName
                viewController.defaultResolution = defaultResolution
                viewController.defaultFPS = defaultFPS
                viewController.maxRecordingTime=maxRecordingTime

                self.viewController?.present(
                    viewController,
                    animated: true,
                    completion: nil
                )

            }
        }

    }

    func videoRecordDidFinish(_ filePath: String, recordedDuration:String, fileSize:String) {
        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
            messageAs:["filePath":filePath,"recordedDuration":recordedDuration, "fileSize":fileSize]
        )

        self.commandDelegate!.send(
            pluginResult,
            callbackId: self.callbackId
        )
    }

    func videoRecordDidFail(error: String) {
        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
            status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR,
            messageAs:error
        )

        self.commandDelegate!.send(
            pluginResult,
            callbackId: self.callbackId
        )
    }
}
```

Everything works ok if I build the app from XCode but when using Ionic console commands for building the app I get the errors: "'VideoRecorderPluginDelegate' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this protocol" and "'VideoRecordingViewController' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class" that are classes declared public inside the framework and using @objc public class, What could I be missing?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was building the framework on a device specific architecture, the problem was solved selecting "Generic iOS Device".